# Passport Number in a Russian Federation Passport for Indian eVisa

Tags: visas, passports

I am applying an India eVisa for a Russian passport holder.
I have two queries.

1. in Passport Surname & Givenname written in Russian and english both. but in english version they just wrote firstname and skipped middlename.. should i just write what is written in english version or i will have to translate the name my self.
2. I am confused at Passport No - passport number is written like 66No20238**. now i am confused, passport number should be 6620238** or 20238**.

Kinldy help me here. if needed i can provide picture of passport.

Comment: I think it's OK if you skip middle name. You should use all digits as Passport No. Not doing an answer since I've not been to India.

Comment: That is _not_ your actual passport number is it? If so, that should really be edited out and replaced with `12No34567` or something like that.

Comment: Ofcourse that is not actual passport number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can confirm your correct passport number by looking at the [machine readable area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport#Passport_booklets) on the bio page. On the second row, the first 9 symbols are the passport number. You should enter that in your visa application.

Similarly, your name should match what's in the machine readable area on row 1. Russian middle name ("father's name") is not what is generally considered a middle name in the Western world, so it is common that it would not show up there.